# i want to modify response by using zuul filter

Tags: spring, netflix-zuul, gateway

i put zuul filter config in my project for modify response.
this is zuul config.
"
zuul:
ignored-patterns: /search/**
routes:
test:
path: /search/**
url: http://localhost:8080/search
sensitive-headers:
"
I wanted that the post filter is executed before response to the user, but the pilter has already responded to the user.

what is wrong..?

i want to know how to use the post zuul filter